# AngularJS calling controller method from a directive with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and starting to work on creating custom directives for one of our projects. Part of the requirement is to create an angular tree and I have took the code from a sample plunkr created by some one. It is not my code and I tried to extend it.

I have to call the controller method with arguments from the directive. I tried with answers on the stack overflow but couldn't solve the issue I am facing. It seems some where I am making a mistake in the recursive calling. The controller method is being called but the argument is undefined. Below is the plnkr code I have.

http://plnkr.co/edit/76iQdnLQyu4k9cn4eId5?p=preview

I appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,
veera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the choiceTree directive's template change:

```
getauditchildren="getchildren(choice.procID)"
```

To:

```
getauditchildren="getchildren({ currentNodeId: choice.procID })
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/fuMCQ9kSWN6Itxzmehth?p=preview

Comment: I am not sure but it worked only for the immediate level and not for 3rd level.

Comment: Will have a look when I have time. Got a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

This does not work when you have multiple levels.
It returns the id of the first level always.
here is a [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuMCQ9kSWN6Itxzmehth?p=preview)

```
getchildren="getauditchildren(currentNodeId)" //should be changed?
```